# Error prediction results in python using Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jupyter-notebook, knn

I created a wood grain image classification system with 3 classes (BAYUR, DAMAR, and SENGON) using the KNN model and implemented it using Flask.

I don't know where is wrong in my code..
Does not show an error but the classification prediction output does not match,
any image that is input the output system only the 'BAYUR' class.
I don't know if it's wrong on flask(made with vscode) or on knn model(made with jupyter notebook).

My python code using Flask for a simple web implementation of the KNN classification model:

```
...
kelas = ['BAYUR', 'DAMAR', 'SENGON']
with open('model_hsv3.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    model = pickle.load(f)

def extract_features_glcms_hsv(image):
    glcm_properties = ['dissimilarity', 'correlation', 'homogeneity', 'contrast', 'ASM', 'energy']

    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    glcm = graycomatrix(gray_image, distances=[1], angles=[0, np.pi/4, np.pi/2, 3*np.pi/4], levels=256,
                        symmetric=True, normed=True)
    glcm_props = [propery for name in glcm_properties for propery in graycoprops(glcm, name)[0]]
    features = [np.mean(hsv_image), np.std(hsv_image)] + glcm_props
    
    # Preprocess the test features
    features = np.array(features).reshape(1, -1)  # reshape to a 2D array

    # Lakukan reshape terhadap nilai features menjadi (n,26) dan simpan dalam DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(features).reshape(-1, 26), columns=[f'feature_{i}' for i in range(26)])

    # Simpan dataframe ke dalam file excel
    df.to_excel("features.xlsx", index=False)

    return features

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/submit", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def predict():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        image = request.files['imagefile']
        filename = image.filename
        image.save(os.path.join('static/uploads', filename))

        img = Image.open(os.path.join('static/uploads', filename))
        img = np.array(img)
        
        img_features = extract_features_glcms_hsv(img)
        # hasil = np.vstack([img_features])np.argmax
        p = model.predict(img_features)
        
        return render_template('index.html', filename=filename, p=kelas[np.argmax(p)])
    return render_template('index.html')

...
```

and my HTML code :

```
...
<div class="contact-image">
    {% if filename %}
    <h4>Citra Serat Kayu</h4>
    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='uploads/' + filename) }}" style= "width:200px;height:200px;" alt="Citra"/>
    <p class="text-center">Jenis Kayu {{ p }}</p>
    {% endif %}
</div>
...
```

I expect the output to match the original class of wood image data that is input, meaning that the predicted results from the KNN model and how to show the wood class predicted results in the flask must be correct.
Please help me...